# Python: PyAutoIt : control_click

Tags: python, autoit

I am trying to simulate a mouse click in specific spot while still being able to control the mouse. From my understanding, I can use the library pyautoit with the command control_click to do this.

For example, I want to click at the location (1097, 832), but want to still be using the mouse when this action is occurring.

The only example I have seen using this command in python is in the code below.

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.win_close("[CLASS:Notepad]")
autoit.control_click("[Class:#32770]", "Button2")
```

This is the function from the library

```
def control_click(title, control, **kwargs):
    """
    :param title:
    :param text:
    :param control:
    :param button:
    :param clicks:
    :param x:
    :param y:
    :return:
    """
    text = kwargs.get("text", "")
    button = kwargs.get("button", "left")
    clicks = kwargs.get("clicks", 1)
    x = kwargs.get("x", INTDEFAULT)
    y = kwargs.get("y", INTDEFAULT)

    ret = AUTO_IT.AU3_ControlClick(LPCWSTR(title), LPCWSTR(text),
                                   LPCWSTR(control), LPCWSTR(button),
                                   INT(clicks), INT(x), INT(y))
    return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

`control_click` does not use the mouse cursor.

`mouse_click` uses the mouse cursor.

`control_click` arguments from *AutoItX.chm* help file are:

> ```
> "title", "text", "controlID" [, button [, clicks [, x [, y ]]]]
> ```

of which the optional argument names align with `**kwargs`.

PyAutoIt arguments from the library for `control_click` are:

> ```
> "title", "control" [, **kwargs]
> ```

where `**kwargs` are optional named arguments.

`**kwargs` accepts named arguments. i.e. `text="some text in the window"`

To click in a control, you could use i.e:

```
autoit.control_click("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", x=1097, y=832)
```

In the library, code you posted, the names for `**kwargs`:

> ```
> text = kwargs.get("text", "")
> button = kwargs.get("button", "left")
> clicks = kwargs.get("clicks", 1)
> x = kwargs.get("x", INTDEFAULT)
> y = kwargs.get("y", INTDEFAULT)
> ```

It is stored as a dictionary and the `.get` method is used to get the value.
If you pass `text="some text in the window"` then `text` equals `some text in the window` else will equal an empty string, represented with `""` in the library, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you can use mouse for two process simultaneously but if you want to use ordinates for click any specific area using `python` and `autoit` below is code for your reference.

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.win_close("[CLASS:Notepad]")
autoit.mouse_click("left",272,70)
```

Above code will left click on **Don't Save** button.
If you have `autoit` installed you can use `AutoIt Window info(x86)` or `AutoIt Window info(x64)` to get the complete details of windows objects.

let me know if above answer is helpful or not.